# Тег "Програмування"

Tags: discussion, tags

З огляду на стрімкий розвиток ІТ в Україні в суспільства є запит на переклад професійних термінів на українську мову. Я вважаю, що необхідно ввести тег "Програмування", або щось подібне, для того, щоб поєднати вже наявні та майбутні питання на цю тему. Впевнений, що подібне введення посприяє розвитку професійної української мови.
На жаль я не можу додати цей тег самостійно, бо не маю достатню кількість балів.

Comment: Краще вже теґ ІТ замість програмування. Бо тоді доведеться перелічити більше 50-ти професій ІТ. Програмування ще поділяється на купу різновидів.

Answer (score 2):

Можливо, згоден, а можливо, і ні — треба подумати.

Це фактично частина ширшого питання (я маю на увазі не конкретне запитання в ме́ті, а питання/тему, що неявно постає) про теги за галузями. Люди постійно намагаються додавати теги за галузями, яких стосуються запитання (програмування, ЗМІ тощо), а не за розділами (чи вузькими підтемами) мовознавства (пунктуація, лексика, наказовий спосіб, відмінювання тощо), а ми постійно їх прибираємо — принаймні, у мене склалося таке враження.

Але, може, ми «воюмо з вітряками», і варто ці теги просто дозволити? (А прибирати хіба що занадто вузькі чи невдалі, як-от Drupal, MS Word тощо.) Я не знаю, над цим треба подумати.

Comment: Погоджуюсь і вважаю, що мають бути теґи десь як катеґорії у словниках: "морська тематика", "програмування", "медицина" тощо. Можливо, треба зробити окреме запитання на меті з вікі-відповіддю, в якій будуть узгоджені теґи (щоб не було нескінченної кількості теґів) + треба буде постійно формувати синоніми.

Comment: Чи з'явилися у вас нові думки з приводу моєї пропозиції? Бо ми все ще "дебажим", "коммітим" та "деплоїм", і не знаєм як то назвати правильно.

Comment: @Oleksandr, зараз мені здається, що якщо є потреба в тегу, то чому б його не додати. (Тобто моя особиста думка: хай теги за галузями — наприклад. «Програмування», «Кулінарія» тощо — теж будуть.) (Єдине що — мабуть, краще [tag:термінологія-програмування], [tag:кулінарна-термінологія] тощо, що просто «програмування», «кулінарія» тощо — але я не наполягаю.)

Answer (score 0):

**Не згоден.** Причин багато, ось найголовніші:

1. Стрімкий розвиток IT — не причина для теґу. Стрімке зростання *кількості запитань на цьому сайті*, натомість, може бути такою причиною. Автор не надав свідчень такого стрімкого зростання.
2. Теґ «програмування» має створюватися **після** теґу «професійна термінологія про IT», який, у свою чергу, має створюватися **після** ще більш широкоохоплюючого теґу «професійна термінологія». Наразі нема свідчень необхідності виділяти навіть найбільш загальну «професійну термінологію».
3. З моєї субʼєктивної точки зору, щоб відповісти, варто чи не варто заводити теґ, треба відповісти на таке запитання:

   > Чи я (або хтось інший) вважаю себе фахівцем з [теґ], у контексті цього сайту?
   >   Чи підпишуся я на розсилку «нові запитання на тему [теґ]»?

   У даному випадку, я вважаю, що більшість користувачів вважають себе фахівцями з української мови (або просто зацікавлені у її розвитку). Вони у рівній мірі цікавляться адекватним перекладом терміну *«to rethrow an exception»* (IT термін) і *«tiebreaker»* (тенісний термін).
4. Тим не менше, ніхто не заважає вам агітувати створення такого теґу (навіть особисто мене можна переконати, що я був неправий). По процедурі створення теґу — бажано облазити цей сайт, **скласти список запитань**, які, на ваш погляд, є хорошими кандидатами. І додати до вашого запитання-ініціативи.
   Це той мінімум, без якого подібна ініціатива загине з-за того, що ніхто нічого не зробив.

Comment: дуже дякую за повну та обґрунтовану відповідь. Я дійсно недостатньо серйозно підготував цю ініціативу.

Comment: Справа в тому, що одні і ті самі слова можна зрозуміти по різному в залежності від галузі використання. Теґи спрощують пошук у випадках пошуку терміну за галуззю. Наприклад, оболонка в ІТ це не те саме, що оболонка в біології чи ще десь.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, це слушне зауваження, але на нього є суттєве заперечення: на сайті **Ukrainian Language**.SE користувачі є фахівцями/аматорами саме **української мови**. Не програмісти, не знавці тенісу, не знавці з підводного плавання, не стоматологи. А саме знавці (або аматори) української мови. Навіть у випадку, якщо декілька з нас, дійсно, є фахівцями з вищезгаданих дисциплін Тому виводити окремий теґ для слів, що стосуються програмування, тенісу, підводного плавання і стоматології — видається зайвим.